# Why does the if statement claim it's false while console.log() says it's true

Tags: javascript, json

This if statement `if(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)) || suicidal){}` is not working as I intended it to.

While the variable Suicidal is working correctly, this condition:

```
JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1))
```

is not;
it's always false even tho

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)))
```

says it's true.

Array4 originated from Array1 and has gone through

```
ArrayX = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array1));
```

3 times.

this is also the only modification that is made to Array1 to get Array4.

Why does it only say True with `console.log()`?

Here is a snippet.

```js
    var suicidal = false;
    var Array1 = [0, 0, 0];
    var Array2;
    var Array3;
    var Array4;

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
    }

    function draw() {
      background(220);
    }

    function mouseClicked() {
      if ((JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1))) || suicidal) { // does not work (suicidal does work)
        line(0, 0, width, height);
      } else {
        if (Array3 != null) {
          Array4 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array3));
        }
        if (Array2 != null) {
          Array3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array2));
        }
        Array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array1));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)));
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

    </head>

    <body>
      <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Put your `console.log` statement *before* the `if` statement, not in the `else` block, to see what values the variables actually have

Comment: Note that you can also use the `Array.prototype.slice` method for cloning an array (shallow).

Comment: Your logic is wrong for `JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)) || suicidal)` you probably want `(JSON.stringify(Array4) == JSON.stringify(Array1)) || suicidal `

Comment: The condition will be true after the third click.

Comment: console.log() says it's true the third time because that's the time it takes to cycle through the arrays by clicking,but if it was true in the if statement, it would not say it is true, but instead draw a line across the gray area because of `line(0, 0, width, height);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(Array1) == "[0, 0, 0]"`.

The first time you click, `JSON.stringify(Array4) == undefined`, so the condition is false, and you go into the `else` block. Both `Array3 != null` and `Array2 != null` are false, so neither of those `if` blocks execute. It then executes `Array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array1))`, so `Array2` is now set. Then you execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)));`, which displays `false`.

The second time you click, `Array4` hasn't changed, so the first `if` fails again, and you go into the `else` block. `Array3 != null` is false, so that `if` is skipped as well. But `Array2 != null` is true, so you assign `Array3`. Then you assign `Array2` again. Then you execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)));`, which displays `false` again.

The third time you click, the first conditions is still false, so you go into the `else` block again. This time you assign `Array4`, `Array3`, and `Array2`. Now `JSON.stringify(Array4) == "[0, 0, 0]"`, so `console.log(JSON.stringify(Array4) == (JSON.stringify(Array1)));` displays `true`.

The next time you click, the first condition will be true, and you'll go into the `if` block. This continues for all future clicks.

The problem is that you're logging the result of the comparison *after* you change the value of `Array4`. So you're not printing the same thing that was used to decide whether to go into the `if` or `else` branch for this click. You're printing what will be used for the *next* click.

Comment: That is correct and I changed the location of the console.log() as such, but even in this case, wouldn't the `if` branch not go into the `else`block but instead go into the `if(true)` block with the next click wich is doesnt do?

Comment: No, It would take 4 clicks to get the value `true`, at first three clicks, all your array will be initiated.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove the error that my answer explains. I spent several minutes on this answer, now it makes no sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll change it back.

Comment: @RaghavGarg I tried to say the same thing but with the fourth click it should go if it's indeed true at that point go into the block of `if(true)` wich will not output another message in the console but instead draw a line across the gray area; right?

Comment: @NoahS I set a breakpoint on the `line(0, 0, width, height)` and it stopped there on the 4th click.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I've corrected it to say that it returns the undefined value.

Comment: @NoahS It's drawing the line. I think you need to set the color so you can see it.